# HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-workstation

Little Background:

My main OS is windows 10. I am using vmware workstation pro. I've installed centos 7 on it.

When I try to install either google chrome or mysql,I am getting the above mentioned output.

How to fix it?

Full trace:

```
[root@localhost ~]# wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stabl_x86_64.rpm
--2023-04-11 10:31:20--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stabl_x86_64.rpm
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 216.58.196.206, 2404:6800:4002:81f::200e
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|216.58.196.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-04-11 10:31:20 ERROR 404: Not Found.


I'm following this tutorial.
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-google-chrome-on-redhat-rhel-fedora-centos-linux/


The same happens when I try to install mysql 

[root@localhost ~]# sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysqy-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm

--2023-04-11 10:30:05--  https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysqy-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
Resolving dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)... 118.214.138.5, 2400:1a00:8000:a84::2e31, 2400:1a00:8000:a81::2e31
Connecting to dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)|118.214.138.5|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-04-11 10:30:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.

I'm following this tutorial for it: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In general questions/problems regarding the usability of or inaccuracies in HOWTO's and manuals should be addressed to their author and not posted on ServerFault. - It should be noted that CentOS 7 is almost a  legacy OS and you should probably not be using it for for fresh installs and/or new deployments in 2023

Comment: we're using it in our company, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply doing this fixed it for me.

```
wget "https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stabl_x86_64.rpm"
```

Comment: (1) **This will not work !** Not sure why you are Posting that here. Both web-links are wrong , hence you will get 404 , whether you use with quotes or without quotes. (2) The Chrome web-link is not available , hence it will give 404. (3) The MySQL web-link is wrong because it has a typo **mysqy** rather than **mysql** & it is missing the version. (4) Try this : https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm , that will work. (5) Likewise , you have to get the Correct web-link for Chrome.